# How to get duplicate values in List<object> using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, c#-4.0

Below is my sample List of object.

```
Person1: Id=1, Name="Test1", Lastname="Test1", Age=13
Person2: Id=2, Name="Test2", Lastname="Test2", Age=14
Person3: Id=3, Name="Test1", Lastname="Test1", Age=15
Person4: Id=4, Name="Test4", Lastname="Test4", Age=16
```

I want to get the duplicate from the List by querying the Name and Lastname.

My new list should be Person1 and Person3.

```
Person1: Id=1, Name="Test1", Lastname="Test1", Age=13
Person3: Id=3, Name="Test1", Lastname="Test1", Age=15
```

How do I achieve this one using LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `groupBy` by multiple properties, `Name and Lastname`. And apply `Where` on the result with `Count>1`, unwind the `groups` with `SelectMany` and convert it back to `List`.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var persons = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person{ Id=1, Name="Test1", Lastname="Test1", Age=13 },
        new Person{ Id=2, Name="Test2", Lastname="Test2", Age=14 },
        new Person{ Id=3, Name="Test1", Lastname="Test1", Age=15 },
        new Person{ Id=4, Name="Test4", Lastname="Test4", Age=16 }
    };

    List<Person> filteredPersons = persons
        .GroupBy(d => new { d.Name, d.Lastname })
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .SelectMany(g => g.ToList())
        .ToList();

    filteredPersons.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Id}: {x.Name} {x.Lastname} {x.Age}"));
}
```

The output will be

```
1: Test1 Test1 13
3: Test1 Test1 15
```